# fix deploy nextjs on heroku?

Tags: deployment

I come to you because I have a problem deploying my nextjs app on heroku I have an error code that tells me that it cannot find the component module.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQXid.png)

```
Failed to compile.
./src/pages/index.tsx:2:19
Type error: Cannot find module '../components/About' or its corresponding type declarations.
  1 | import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'
> 2 | import About from '../components/About'
    |                   ^
  3 | import Contact from '../components/Contact'
  4 | import Main from '../components/Main'
  5 | import Navbar from '../components/Navbar'
-----> Build failed
       
       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
       
       Some possible problems:
       
       - Node version not specified in package.json
         https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version
       
       Love,
       Heroku
       
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed
```

I can't understand that it module is missing, it does this to me for all the components.

If anyone has a solution, I'm interested

I checked the package.json but nothing to report.

I have the latest version of node, npm, and git.

I have no error locally there is no database it is only a static portfolio.

I modified the next start in json .

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start -p $PORT",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for case sensitivity in the file system: Verify that the file system you're deploying to is case-sensitive, as certain environments (such as macOS and Linux) are case-sensitive while others (such as Windows) are not. If the file system is case-sensitive, ensure that the file names and paths in your imports match the exact casing of the actual files.

Comment: it's on a windows environment so I don't know if it's a case problem

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).